# Python why does issubclass(int, float) return False

Tags: python, oop, floating-point, int, subclass

In Python, why do both `issubclass(int, float)` and `isinstance(1, float)` return `False`?

I always thought that `int` is a subclass of `float`.

```py
In [1]: issubclass(int, float)
Out[1]: False

In [2]: isinstance(1, float)
Out[2]: False
```

---

**Research**

https://github.com/Stewori/pytypes/issues/26

Mentions [`The numeric tower][1]` from PEP 484, but I think that's for type hints.

Comment: Not sure how anyone can answer this. Why would you think int was a subclass of float?

Comment: `int` and `float` have completely different implementations, due to the "unlimitied size" of Python `int`. There's no reason for one to inherit from the other.

Comment: @Carcigenicate They are implemented in stdlib [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html). But those ABCs have virtually nothing to do with built-in types `int` and `float`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the premise was simply a misconception.   @OP:  since you mentioned the numeric tower, you are probably just confused by the ABCs, in which expressions like `issubclass(numbers.Integral, numbers.Rational)` and `isinstance(1, numbers.Complex)` are true.

Comment: You all can downvote this if you want.  In my defense, I think the question is clearly worded, the comments/answers provide clarity and point out an answer.  Why would this not add value to new developers (like me), who may have the same question?

Comment: I have not **downvoted** your question. I did vote to close the question, because I feel it's not useful for future reference. If we have a post for every question which was based on a mistaken premise, then that would make up 99% of the content on here. But, anyway, that's just my own opinion and there would have to 2 others agreeing for the closure to happen.

Comment: I guess I agree.  Thanks for clearing me up regardless :)

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer I agree. Your question is very clear. Hopefully you have cleared up your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `int` is not a subclass of `float`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(int)
(<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> inspect.getmro(float)
(<class 'float'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: I don't think that will help OP. It's just restating what they've already discovered in a slightly different way.